# jquery mobile change checkbox color to white

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and i just want to set the background of an unchecked checkbox to white. I tried to do this with themeroller but couldn't find the option. In addition playing around with css didn't solve the problem as well. So what is the right css class to do this?
To make it clear the checkbox itself should be white not the sorrunding label.

Comment: your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Why can't you use custom checkbox..
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>        
    <style>
        .checkbox {
            display: inline-block !important;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 25px !important;  
            margin: 0px !important;              
        }
        input[type=checkbox] {
            display: none;
        }
        .checkbox:before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox:before {
            content: "\2713";
            background-color: #0088cc;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <input data-role="none" id="Option" type="checkbox"/>
    <label data-role="none" class="checkbox" for="Option"> Alerts </label>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what i wanted to have. The checkbox itself should be white not the label surrounding. I always try to use predefined components instead of making custom ones but if this is not possible here i'll try with that.

Answer (score 3):

background is added to `label` within a div `ui-checkbox` wrapping checkbox itself.

You need to override `label`'s background with class `ui-checkbox-off`. Use `!important` to force override.

```
/* un-checked */
.ui-checkbox label.ui-checkbox-off {
  background: white !important;
}

/* checked */
.ui-checkbox label.ui-checkbox-on {
  background: #00b0eb !important;
}
```

To change the color of the checkbox itself, use `:after` pseudo selector to override `background-color` not `background`.

```
.ui-checkbox-off:after {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.ui-checkbox-on:after {
  background-color: #00b0eb !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4AMeT/)**

Comment: nice and clean as always. I was to slow ;)